# upgrade pip version deployed Azure function App

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have an Azure function App deployed. I upgraded my local pip version from 20.2.3 to 22.3. Now when I deployed new version, I'm getting this warning from vscode. How can I upgrade pip version. Need some help.

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Not sure how to run the command like where to login and execute to upgrade the pip any suggestions?

Here is more detailed output...
[20:18:00+0000] Successfully built pyodbc
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the above issue, please check the below steps

- Before updating the python version in azure portal

[image]

- In azure portal Run the below command in azure CLI

```
az functionapp config set --name "FunctionAppName" --resource-group "YourResourceGroup" --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.9"
```

After executing the command, we can see python version as be updated

[image]

References taken from Docs [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest)&[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,azurecli-linux,application-level#changing-python-version)

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and update here. :)

Comment: command above didn't have syntax for upgrading PIP Version. Please see. I want to upgrade the PIP Version.

Comment: Currently the Azure function in consumption plan it doesn't allow changing basic pip version. I even tried with requirements.txt it didn't work.

Comment: It can be done in functions premium plan