# Error in function azure when updating runtime python - Failure Exception: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, python-3.7, python-3.8

I've got an error when I try to update the python runtime of a function Azure, from 3.6 to 3.7 or 3.8, because version 3.6 is no longer used in Azure.

This is the full error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 355, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 127, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/site/wwwroot/CopyTransactionHttpTrigger/__init__.py", line 8, in <module> from confluent_kafka import avro File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/confluent_kafka/__init__.py", line 18, in <module> _delvewheel_init_patch_16682001180() File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/confluent_kafka/__init__.py", line 9, in _delvewheel_init_patch_16682001180 os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
```

`Python 3.7 and 3.8`

modules in requirements.txt file:
`azure-functions==1.12.0 confluent-kafka==1.7.0 confluent-kafka[avro]==1.7.0 requests azure.storage.blob`

I tried to update the function Azure with python 3.7 and 3.8 installing all dependencies above (modules) with such runtimes.

I think this module is necessary => module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory', and I don't know how to solve it.

What I see on the documentation of [os module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory), it's used for windows. Do I need this module (os) in Azure?, can I avoid it by code?, if so, how?

Comment: Refer to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129926/upgrade-pip-version-deployed-azure-function-app/74161502#74161502)

Answer (score 0):

I just install the function in linux on my local machine and deploy it from there adn it works. The issue was that I was deplying form a windows environtment.